# In Rails do you have to re-assign all instance variables before rendering?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm making a practice app where I implement a resource (Task) manually instead of using Rails' built-in functionality.

The index page lists tasks and has a form to create a new task. If there is an error when submitting, the index page is rendered and the errors are displayed on the page.

**My question is**: Does every instance variable assignment in the index action need to be copied over to the create action so that it knows how to render the index page? Or is there some way to pass just the @task instance variable to the index action and let it take care of everything else?

Right now I'm only copying over one line from the index action to the create action:

```
@tasks = Task.all
```

but I imagine in more complex apps you may have many instance variables in a single action, so I would guess there is some alternative to copying them over to all actions that render the same page.

Comment: use `before_filter :set_tasks, :only => [:new, :create, ...]`

Answer (score 1):

In your controller do :

```
before_filter :set_instances, only: [:index, :create]

private
  def set instances
    @tasks = Task.all
    @task = Task.new
    ...
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use filters on and call them only on new create e.i

```
 class TasksController < ApplicationController
      before_filter :set_tasks,:only => [:index, :new, :create]
    def index
    ...
    end        

    def new
    ...
    end

    def create
     .....
    end
     def set_tasks
       @tasks = Task.all
       @task = Task.new
    end
end
```